# Adding number of remaining counts for getting a badge for all the badges - kinda progress on badges

Tags: feature-request

Why Stackoverflow think about adding a counts remaining to for that particular badges possible . It will encourage users to get new badges. I know it is not possible for all badges but it will be good.

The badge "Strunk & White" will be given to user if user edits 80 posts. Suppose if user edits 60 posts, Then "20 remaining" text can be put next to the badge or on hovering the badge. It will help users to reach the goal.

Comment: Useful link: [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)

Comment: Badges are supposed to be a fun little reward for normal usage of the site. They're not really supposed to be something you go hunting for.

Answer (score 1):

Progress indicators for a few badges are displayed. Progress for Reviewer/Steward, Civic Duty, Strunk&White/Copy Editor, and Electorate is displayed on the Review page.

[image]

The Review link is displayed only if you have review privileges but a direct link is also accessible such as http://www.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats. Hover on the progress bar and a popup will appear showing badge progress.